# Bounding the probability of sum of positive random variables exceeding a constant

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I have two independent r.v.s $X,Y$ and I want to find,

$$\mathbb P (|X|+|Y| > t)$$

then can we have an upper bound calculation on the above probability like so?

We have the only following events which sum up to 1.
$$E_1=\{|X|> t/2, |Y| > t/2) \}, E_2=\{|X|> t/2, |Y| < t/2) \}, E_3 = \{|X|< t/2, |Y| > t/2) \}, E_4=\{|X|< t/2, |Y| < t/2) \}$$

Since the last event $E_4$ implies that $\{|X|+|Y| < t \}$ or $$\mathbb P (E_4) < \mathbb P (|X|+|Y| < t) \implies \mathbb P(E_1)+ \mathbb P(E_2)+ \mathbb P(E_3) > \mathbb P(|X|+|Y| > t)\\ \implies \mathbb P(|X| > t/2)+\mathbb P(|Y|> t/2) > \mathbb P(|X|+|Y| > t) $$

Is such a reasoning correct? If so are the constants $t/2$ arbitrary? (can we have $t/3$ and $2t/3$? Is there a generalization to this where the variables need not be positive?

NOTE: I am not worried about $<$ or $\leq$ since I am dealing with continuous r.v.s.

Comment: The main thing is that $A \subset B \implies P(A) \leq P(B)$.

Comment: @Mason yep....but the above idea seems a bit arbitrary. Hence I want to double check

Comment: It is a bit arbitrary as you said. You can use $at$ and $bt$ where $a+b=1$.

Comment: @Mason maybe you can formulate an answer. I can  see this happening for not necessarily positive random variables too.